# Identifying and Counting strings in a dataframe R

Tags: r

I'm very new to R and I'm trying to write some lines that will help me identify and count some strings I'm importing to R from Excel. The data looks like this:

```
id           Solutions                           PFBA(R_Biomass_LPAREN_e_RPAREN_)
1   R_PEPCK R_TRANSH2 R_PGI R_GLUCK                         1.1750060160861004
2   R_PEPCK R_TRANSH2 R_PGI R_G1D                           1.1750060160861004
3   R_PFK R_6PGDH R_PYK R_PGM R_MAL1 R_MAL2 R_TALA2 R_G6P1D 3.2099449405406175
4   R_PFK R_6PGDH R_PYK R_PGM R_MAL1 R_MAL2 R_R5PI R_G6P1D  3.2099449405406175
5   R_PFK R_6PGDH R_PYK R_PGM R_MAL1 R_MAL2 R_TKT1 R_G6P1D  3.2099449405406175
6   R_6PGDH R_PYK R_PGM R_PGI R_MAL1 R_MAL2 R_TALA2 R_G6P1D 2.0012655526190235
7   R_6PGDH R_PYK R_PGM R_PGI R_MAL1 R_MAL2 R_R5PI R_G6P1D  2.0012655526190235
8   R_6PGDH R_PYK R_PGM R_PGI R_MAL1 R_MAL2 R_TKT1 R_G6P1D  2.0012655526190235
```

My goal is to go through the 'solutions' column and identify reactions (when a new one appears) and count them. At the end my ideal output would be something like:

```
R_PEPCK: 15
R_TRANHS2: 5
R_PGI: 2
(Etc...)
```

where it returns me an organized list with all the reactions and the number of times they appeared in the solutions column.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

Sample data

```
df <- data.frame(Solutions = c('R_PEPCK R_TRANSH2 R_PGI R_GLUCK', 'R_PEPCK R_TRANSH2 R_PGI R_G1D', 'R_PFK R_6PGDH R_PYK R_PGM R_MAL1 R_MAL2 R_TALA2 R_G6P1D'), stringsAsFactors = F)

                                                Solutions
1                         R_PEPCK R_TRANSH2 R_PGI R_GLUCK
2                           R_PEPCK R_TRANSH2 R_PGI R_G1D
3 R_PFK R_6PGDH R_PYK R_PGM R_MAL1 R_MAL2 R_TALA2 R_G6P1D
```

Counts of unique strings (separated by spaces):

```
counts <- as.matrix(table(unlist(strsplit(df$Solutions, split = '\\W'))), ncol = 1)

          [,1]
R_6PGDH      1
R_G1D        1
R_G6P1D      1
R_GLUCK      1
R_MAL1       1
R_MAL2       1
R_PEPCK      2
R_PFK        1
R_PGI        2
R_PGM        1
R_PYK        1
R_TALA2      1
R_TRANSH2    2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a `tidyverse` solution:

```
df %>%
  separate_rows(Solutions, sep = " ") %>%
  count(Solutions)

# A tibble: 13 x 2
   Solutions     n
   <chr>     <int>
 1 R_6PGDH       1
 2 R_G1D         1
 3 R_G6P1D       1
 4 R_GLUCK       1
 5 R_MAL1        1
 6 R_MAL2        1
 7 R_PEPCK       2
 8 R_PFK         1
 9 R_PGI         2
10 R_PGM         1
11 R_PYK         1
12 R_TALA2       1
13 R_TRANSH2     2
```